# How can I solve this error to make an secondary y axis in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis, geom-bar

I run the code to make two graphs in one dimension(i.e. secondary y axis) in R, but the geom_line graph does not shown.

I want to make a secondary y axis graph in R by combining geom_line and geom_bar.

I want these two graphs(geom_line and geom_bar) to be represented at once through secondary yaxis, but after I run the code, it only shows the graphic of geom_bar and the warning happened. How can I change my code to show both of the graphs at once?

```
odd_weather = pge[seq_len(nrow(pge)) %% 2 == 1, ]
odd_weather
```

```
ggplot(data = pge) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Date, y = Usage),
           width = 0.8,
           colour = 'steelblue3',
           fill = 'steelblue3',
           stat = "identity") +
  geom_label(aes(x = Date, y = Usage), label = ifelse(Date == as.Date("2021-09-01"), "Sep", NA), hjust = 0.3, vjust = -11.2, size = 3) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = Date, y = Weather),
            color = 'purple') +
  geom_label(data = odd_weather,
             mapping = aes(x = Date, y = Weather, label = paste(Weather, sep = ','))) +
  geom_smooth(mapping = aes(x = Date, y = Weather), method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 3), se = FALSE) +
  scale_x_date(
    name = " ", 
    breaks = seq.Date(as.Date("2021-08-27"), as.Date("2021-09-24"), by = "4 days"),
    date_labels = "%a\n%d") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = " ",
    limits = c(0, 8),
    breaks = seq(0.0, 8.0, by = 2.0), 
    labels = c('0.0', '2.0', '4.0', '6.0', '8.0'),
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*15, name = " ")) +
  annotate("segment", x = median(c(as.Date("2021-08-31"), as.Date("2021-09-01"))), xend = median(c(as.Date("2021-08-31"), as.Date("2021-09-01"))), y = 0, yend = 8.0, colour = 'gray88', size = 0.5) +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = 'gray96'),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'gray96'),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = 'gray88',
                                          size = 0.3,
                                          linetype = 1),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 8),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8))
```

This is my current code, and the result shown as the first picture.

[image]

And I want to make my graph like the second one.
[image]

Comment: Hi Seoyoung. We can only guess because you have not included the data in your question, but it seems likely that you are not seeing the data points for Weather because you have not transformed it. The secondary axis does not automatically change your data. It just back-transforms the axis range. Try using `y = Weather/15` inside `aes` in `geom_line`, `geom_label` and `geom_smooth` - at present your `ylim` is removing all values of weather greater than 8 (that's why you are getting the warning about 32 rows being removed)

Comment: Oh, thank you so much for your help. I was staying up all night because of this problem and then finally I just solved it all at once thanks to your comment.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.